# Fully connected after Spatial Pyramid Pooling

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Must there be a fully connected layer after a Spatial pyramid pooling layer when doing classification? Or can convolutional layers be used after the Spatial pyramid pooling layer?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the TensorFlow definition of Spatial pyramid pooling ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/v0.11.2/tensorflow_addons/layers/spatial_pyramid_pooling.py)), it seems like the output is flattened. So in that case, only 1D convolution would make sense. However, if there are any spatial information left for a convolution to learn I don't know.

**EDIT:** After a quick investigation of what the Spatial pyramid pooling algorithm does, I do not think that it is a good idea to use any convolution. That is because there is no real spatial information left in the data. That is also how it is used, see for example [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4729).

Comment: Thanks Marcus for answering. But I need an answer with higher insight

Comment: @amin71 I see, but I think you need to be more precise in your question and maybe provide a description of your specific case for someone to give you a more insightful answer.

Comment: I am working on images and I want to pass the feature map first through a Spatial pyramid pooling layer

Comment: @amin71 Alright, but after passing through a Spatial pyramid pooling layer, the data is one dimensional right? Thus, 2D-convolution is not possible. Citing the abstract of the original article "In this work, we equip the networks with another pooling strategy [than convolution], 'spatial pyramid pooling', to eliminate the above requirement [of fixed-size images]". The technique is originally meant to be used instead of convolution, and not alongside it.